# How do I configure traefik w/ docker-compose to route more than one port for a service

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I would like to configure traefik via docker-compose to expose more than one port of a component service.

For instance, when serving an `ember-cli` app, how can I expose both the main port and the live-reload port for development?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to bind multiple ports of a container, you have to use the traefik..* labels described here in the [documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/). For example something like this could be used in docker-compose.yml

```
  labels:
    - traefik.ember.port=8080
    - traefik.ember.frontend.rule=Host:mydomain.com
    - traefik.reload.port=37531
    - traefik.reload.frontend.rule=Host:mydomain.com;PathPrefixStrip:/reload
```

Comment: Their documentation is currently down, and was experiencing SSL issues today :(

Comment: their documentation is available again, so the link now works @9ilsdx9rvj0lo

Comment: Turns out they were updating their website/documentation and expected several outages during the day.

Comment: It seems that their documentation paths were changed to [here](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/)